# Corda shell "No Matching Constructor found:" but doesnt specify flow constructor parameters

Tags: corda

So I finished the bootcamp_cordapp and tried to recreate it using the cordapp_template_java, I successfully recreated the tokenIssueFlow and successfully ran the flow tests, but whenever I tried to start the flow using the shell, this appears.

[image: shell screenshot]

I checked the gradle files, and all of them already have this in them.

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-parameters"
}
```

I'm still learning corda and I would appreciate whoever could help me with this.

Comment: What do you see in the shell if you just type `flow start TemplateTokenIssueFlow`? That should spit out the list of expected arguments.

Comment: this is the output when i just type flow start TemplateTokenIssueFlow

![shell screenshot](https://image.ibb.co/gEVmOA/image.png)

Comment: Odd. Can you post the flow definition in the question? You can leave out the logic in `call` :)

Answer (score 1):

When you get this error, you should try running the flow without any arguments at all:

```
flow start TemplateTokenIssueFlow
```

This will then list out the available constructors in the shell.

Comment: Where does the shell pick up the constructor's definition from?